Call useState() with value or function?
It isn't really a problem but I'm seeking some new understanding in React.useState().
The program below runs as expected, however I am not sure if it's the correct way for performing my task.
Task is to use React.useState(0) to add and subtract and display the changes in the web browser.
function App(){
    const [myValue , setmyValue] = React.useState(0);
    function addValue(value){
        value = value + 1;
        return value;
    }
    function subValue(value){
        value = value - 1;
        return value;
    }
    function handleAdd(){
        //setmyValue( myValue + 1);
         setmyValue(addValue(myValue))
    }
    function handleSub(){
        setmyValue(myValue - 1);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleAdd}>+</button>
            <p>{myValue}</p>
            <button onClick={handleSub}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("part1"));

Any advice if passing the value myValue directly to thesetValue() function is correct or passing another function is the correct way.

You are using it correctly, but I think it could be simplified more this way.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(0);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setMyValue(prevValue => prevValue + 1);
  };

  const handleSub = () => {
    setMyValue(prevValue => prevValue - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myValue}</p>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>+</button>
      <button onClick={handleSub}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;



passing another function

IIUC, you refer to your code sample:
//setmyValue( myValue + 1);
setmyValue(addValue(myValue))

In that case, to be exact, you are not passing a function, but a value which is the result of executing a function (addValue(myValue)).
In this very case, as implied by DevonRay's answer, it seems overkill, but should addValue perform more complex operations, there would be nothing wrong in doing so.

Now there is actually the possibility to pass an "updater" function to your setmyValue state setter:

If you pass a function as nextState, it will be treated as an updater function. It [...] should take the pending state as its only argument, and should return the next state.

That is actually what your addValue function does:
function addValue(value) { // Takes the pending state as only parameter
  value = value + 1;
  return value; // Returns the next state
}

So you could pass the reference to the function to the state setter to use the updater mode:
setmyValue(addValue); // addValue is NOT executed right away, you just pass its reference

In your very case, there will be no visible difference, but let's illustrate with a slightly different scenario: let's say you want to add 2 (instead of 1) to your value:
Of course we could do setmyValue(myValue + 2), it does work, end of the story.
But one could also try doing:
setmyValue(myValue + 1);
setmyValue(myValue + 1); // Try adding 1 again, so that in total 2 is added

In this case, it will not work as expected: the new state will be incremented only by 1, because the last call to setmyValue state setter still uses the "stale" version of myValue, i.e. the same value as before the first call, as if the latter did not have any effect. myValue is a const, after all.
But if we use the updater mode, at least for the next call(s):
setmyValue(myValue + 1);
setmyValue(addValue); // Add 1 again

...now it works!
The reason is that React will pass to addValue updater function the pending state, i.e. the actual result of the first call.
See the example in the linked doc for more explanation.

The way you're using useState is fine but you can simplify this code quite a lot as per below:
function App(){
    const [myValue , setmyValue] = React.useState(0);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setmyValue(myValue++)}>+</button>
            <p>{myValue}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setmyValue(myValue--)}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("part1"));


In answer to your question as a whole throug, for simple flows pass the value but if you need to do complex functions use a function.

This is a very unsafe way to update state based on the current value

@Phil agreed if there were any effects off this or other areas where the state was managed, but for this example it works and is safe.
